# KUbuntu 17.10. under vbox: installing innotek display driver makes taskbar disappear

Tags: drivers, virtualbox, kubuntu

Installed KUbuntu 17.10 in a VirtualBox 5.2.2 VM under Win7SP1x64 host. The installation finished normally and everything seemed to work fine until i went to Settings / Driver Manager and installed the Innotek VirtualBox Graphics Adapter. Now, after restarting the VM and logging-in, the taskbar appears for less than 1" and then disappears. Trying to start any application does nothing (or perhaps the application window opens, but does not appear on screen, much like the taskbar).

It seems the taskbar is there, not visible though because when i click where the "Start" launcher button is supposed to be, the launcher menu appears and i can click on an application. As i said above though, the application window is either not shown or the application does not start at all.

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour? Is there a solution to it? I can't be sure if it's a driver issue (as it seems) or a virtualbox issue, so i'm not even sure what to report and where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here...

My workaround is to disable the 3D-Acceleration in VBox...

[image]